# Android: Parse.com concurrency issue with findInBackground()

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am using `Parse.com` as a backend for my app. The local database from `Parse` seems to be very easy to use, so I decided to use it.

I want to create a database with `Name` and `PhoneNumber`. That is easy, just make a `new ParseObject` and `pinInBackground()`. But it is more complicated when I want to remove duplicate numbers. First I need to search if the number already exists in the database and then add the new number if it doesn't exists.

The method to do this is:

```
 public void putPerson(final String name, final String phoneNumber, final boolean isFav) {

    // Verify if there is any person with the same phone number
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseClass.PERSON_CLASS);
    query.whereEqualTo(ParseKey.PERSON_PHONE_NUMBER_KEY, phoneNumber);
    query.fromLocalDatastore();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                               public void done(List<ParseObject> personList,
                                                ParseException e) {
                                   if (e == null) {
                                       if (personList.isEmpty()) {
                                           // If there is not any person with the same phone number add person
                                           ParseObject person = new ParseObject(ParseClass.PERSON_CLASS);
                                           person.put(ParseKey.PERSON_NAME_KEY, name);
                                           person.put(ParseKey.PERSON_PHONE_NUMBER_KEY, phoneNumber);
                                           person.put(ParseKey.PERSON_FAVORITE_KEY, isFav);

                                           person.pinInBackground();
                                       } else {
                                           Log.d(TAG, "Warning: " + "Person with the number " + phoneNumber + " already exists.");
                                       }
                                   } else {
                                       Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                   }
                               }
                           }
    );

}
```

Lets say I want to add 3 persons in the database:

```
    ParseLocalDataStore.getInstance().putPerson("Jack", "0741234567", false);
    ParseLocalDataStore.getInstance().putPerson("John", "0747654321", false);
    ParseLocalDataStore.getInstance().putPerson("Jack", "0741234567", false);
    ParseLocalDataStore.getInstance().getPerson(); // Get all persons from database
```

Notice that first and third person have the same number so the third souldn't be added to database, but...

The `logcat` after this is:

```
12-26 15:37:55.424 16408-16408/D/MGParseLocalDataStore: Person:0741234567 was added.
12-26 15:37:55.424 16408-16408/D/MGParseLocalDataStore: Person:0747654321 was added.
12-26 15:37:55.484 16408-16408/D/MGParseLocalDataStore: Person:0741234567 was added.
12-26 15:37:55.494 16408-16408/D/MGParseLocalDataStore: Person database is empty
```

The last line from `logcat` is from the method that shows me all persons from database:

```
public void getPerson() {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseClass.PERSON_CLASS);
        query.fromLocalDatastore();
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> personList,
                             ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (personList.isEmpty()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Person database is empty");
                    } else {
                    for (ParseObject p : personList) {
                        Log.d(TAG, p.getString(ParseKey.PERSON_PHONE_NUMBER_KEY));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
}
```

So there are 2 problems:

1. The third number is added even if I checked if already exists.
2. The method that shows me all persons tell me I have nothing in my database even if in logcat I can see it added 3 persons.

**I think the problem is findInBackground() method that does all the job in another thread.
Is there any solution to this problem?**

Comment: have you heard about Parse Cloud Code? You can do this type of verification on the back-end. :)

Comment: He is working with localdatastore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your problems are a result of asynchronous work. If you call the `putPerson` method twice, they will both run near-simultaneously in separate background threads and both find-queries will most likely return almost at the same time, and definitely before the first call has saved the new person.

In your example, the `getPerson` call will return before the background threads have been able to save your three people as well.

Your problem is not really related to Parse or localDataStore, but is a typical concurrency issue. You need to rethink how you handle concurrency in your app.

As long as this is only a local issue, you can impose synchronous structure with i.e. the [Bolts Framework](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android) (which is already a part of your app since you're using Parse). But if calls to `addPerson` is done in multiple places, you will always face this problem and you'd have to find other solutions or workarounds to handle concurrency.

Concurrency is a big topic which you should spend some time studying.

Comment: I learned about threads and concurency in java, but never used them before working with android. I will read about Bolts and how to handle concurrency. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The link you provided is for iOS. This https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android is for Android if someone is looking for it.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Was a little quick on my google->cut->paste :-)  I have fixed the link now